# Find consecutive sub sequence of x variable from last without for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, sequence

I have a dataframe

```
  Order Priority Year_Month_vphrase_v1
           M              Jan-2017
           M              Feb-2017
           H              Mar-2017
           L              Apr-2017
           C              May-2017
           M              Jun-2017
           H              Jul-2017
           M              Aug-2017
           M              Sep-2017
           M              Oct-2017
           M              Nov-2017
```

I want to find how many times `M` has occurred from below consecutively. So for example it should return `n = 4` as from below it is coming consecutively `4` times.

It can be done with the help of for loop after reversing the dataframe. Is there any way without for loop to find?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pandas`:

```
>>> df['Order Priority'].eq('M').diff().ne(0).cumsum().to_frame(0).groupby(0)[0].count().max()
4
>>>
```